# how to set a page active automatically when it is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i want to change the active class when each page loaded. my jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.nav li a').click(function(e) {

    $('.nav li a.active').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

and my html code is

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked bg-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_home"><span     class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp;Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_student">Student</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_teacher">Teacher</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_parent">Parent</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_subject">Subject</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_class">Class</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_exam">Exam</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_mark_attendence">Marks</a>    </li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_grade">Exam Grade</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_routine">Class Routine</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_payment">Payment</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_library">Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_transport">Transport</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_notice">Notice Board</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_settings">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/admin_profile">Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
```

the problems are
1. it does not shows the first page ie. home.. as active. others are okey
2. it does not redirect to the url defined in the href.

Comment: It doesn't redirect because you're telling it not to. `e.preventDefault()` prevents the anchor from performing the default action of redirecting the page. Did you research that function before you tried to use it? Anyway, you aren't the first person to want to add an active class to links - this problem has been solved thousands of times before. Try searching for some examples first, then come back here if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The logic can be used in Codeigniter using PHP, I think you don't need to use jquery here like,

if you are calling `admin_student` function in controller then pass active class for that `li` like,

```
// in controller
$activeClass='admin_student';
```

And in the view page use a switch-case like,

```
$activeClass=isset($activeClass) ? $activeClass : 'admin_home';
$admin_student='';//make variables for all li
$admin_home='';
switch($activeClass){
    case 'admin_student':
        $admin_student='active';
        break;
    ....
    default:
        $admin_home='active';
        break;
}
```

And add this variable to your `li` like,

```
<li class="<?php echo $admin_home;?>"><a href="...">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php echo $admin_student;?>"><a href="...">Student</a></li>
```

This will solve your first problem, and the second problem occurs because of using `e.preventDefault()` so don't use it if you want redirection of URLs.

Comment: it is nice.. but i am not calling this file directly  from the controller

Comment: Then you can use helpers and make function to get the active class